# How to display only .rst headers in Sphinx sidebar navigation?

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar, toctree

I'm creating a documentation in Sphinx using this theme:
https://github.com/romnnn/sphinx_press_theme

I'm having trouble achieving the intended navigation sidebar, which should ideally reflect the headers of each of my `.rst` files - e.g.:

```
Contents:
 Introduction
  About
```

To try and achieve this, I've set up the below structure:

**index.rst**

```
===========================
Contents:
===========================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   introduction/introduction
```

**introduction/introduction.rst:**

```
=======================
Introduction
=======================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   about/about

Introduction Sub Header 1
__________________________
```

**introduction/about/about.rst:**

```
=======================
About
=======================
```

When I use no theme, this leads to the below (which is almost what I'm looking for, but I would like to not show the page sub headers).

```
Contents:
 Introduction
  About
  Introduction Sub Header 1
```

When I use the aforementioned theme, I get the below result where only the sub header shows - I'd like instead to show the About page header.

```
Contents:
 Introduction
  Introduction Sub Header 1
```

Is there some way to modify this behavior to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by "When I use no theme"? Do you mean the default theme (alabaster)?

Comment: That's correct. Eventually I found that this was not easily solved within the specific theme I intended to use and I now switched to the standard Read the Docs theme with a custom CSS file to get the result I wanted.